# \multicolumn in a table

Tags: tables

How can I put "Barclays Premier League Table" on two rows if it is longer than the size of the two columns (1cm+1cm)?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Für Umlaute
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}


\begin{tabular}{p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Barclays Premier League Table} &  \# \\
Position & Club & Points \\
\hline
1      & Chelsea    & 59      \\
2      & Tottenham  & 50      \\
3      & Man City   & 49      \\
4      & Arsenal    & 47      \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{p{2cm}}{Barclays ...}` but a multirow would be better even, I think.Please replace `german` with `ngerman` for `babel`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest a `tabularx` approach and using an `X` columntype for the 2nd column, since that one will have the widest entries (the names of the Premier League Clubs)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Für Umlaute
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}

\newlength{\spaltenbreite}
\setlength{\spaltenbreite}{1.0cm}

\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{p{\spaltenbreite}Xp{\spaltenbreite}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Barclays Premier League Table} &  \# \\
Position & Club & Points \\
\hline
1      & Chelsea    & 59      \\
2      & Tottenham  & 50      \\
3      & Man City   & 49      \\
4      & Arsenal    & 47      \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `p` types could be replaced with `r`, I think

Answer (score 5):

You may want to make the string span all three columns of the table, so that it reads like a caption -- which, I believe, is its function. I'd use the basic `c` column type for the first and third column, and I'd allow line wrapping to happen in the second column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % 'german' option is for "historic" documents, right?
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c >{\raggedright}p{3cm} c @{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Barclays Premier League Table} \\
Position & Club & \# Points \\
\hline
1      & Chelsea    & 59      \\
2      & Tottenham  & 50      \\
3      & Man City   & 49      \\
4      & Arsenal    & 47      \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```